# How to get result from beforeunload event prompt in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

When closing a window/tab I want to check the user status and if it has specific value - show prompt asking whether to close window/tab or not. And if the the user chose 'Close' call a function and quit. That's how I've implemented it -

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeClose(e) {
    if (this.ui.callInfo.status !== 'disconnected') {
      let confirmationMessage = '\o/';
      e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;

      return confirmationMessage;
    }
    return;
  }

  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  onClose(e) {
    this.ui.hangup();
  }
```

However while `beforeunload` event handler works fine, `unload` doesn't seem to call the method. Is there something wrong? **Maybe there is another solution, which allows to check the result of** `beforeunload` **popup?**